# Winterbash 2013 hat overview showing my avatar without a hat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2013

I visited the [Winterbash 2013 hat overview](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/) page, logged in and noticed my avatar (displayed next to the logout link) wears no hat, even though I wear hats for all sites.

Comment: Ironically enough, looks like by design.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd what a shame! :-)

Comment: FWIW, this is fixed for Winter Bash 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. Could be a feature request to make it sport your hat, though I expect it'd land fairly low on the priority list. Unless it's ridiculously easy, in which case it'd happen in about three seconds. But if that were the case, it'd probably have been done already. Unless it was an oversight, in which case a feature request would help. And down the rabbit hole we go...

Comment: That's why you didn't yet tag this status-bydesign? :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd In case the OP wanted to turn it into a feature request.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller To me, it’s not that important. Just a minor inconsistency I wanted to report. I think there’s more important work to do than this on SE.